# How to upload file to google drive with asp.net web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I used code for upload for console application.
its working but for web client api.. its not working for web application ...
I got null for `Responsebody=null`.

here is my code:

```
 ClientSecrets secrets = new ClientSecrets()
 {
        ClientId = parameters.ClientId,
        ClientSecret = parameters.ClientSecret
 };
 var token = new TokenResponse { RefreshToken = parameters.RefreshToken };
 var credentials = new UserCredential(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(
      new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
      {
            ClientSecrets = secrets
      }),
      Environment.UserName,
      token);
 var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
 {
           HttpClientInitializer = credentials,
           ApplicationName = "Google Drive",
 });

 if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
 {
      var filename = FileUpload1.FileName;
      var filepath = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
      Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File body = new Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File();
      body.Title = filename;
      body.Description = "Documents";
      body.MimeType =GetMimeType(filename);
      body.Parents = new List<ParentReference>() { new ParentReference() { Id = "0BySorYm3rcaNeXV2Y0M5bXh1WjA" } };
      //byte[] array = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);
      MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(FileUpload1.FileBytes);
      FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload fileuploadrequest = new FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload(service, body, stream, GetMimeType(filename));
      //var name=MediaFileSource.GetContentTypeForFileName(filename);
      //fileuploadrequest.Convert = true;
      //fileuploadrequest.OauthToken=parameters.AccessToken;
      fileuploadrequest.Upload();
      //geting null using this code and also not getting error for upload
      Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File response = fileuploadrequest.ResponseBody;
```

Comment: console application is using other application type from console.developer.google.com. and its working but when i use for web application its not working.plz give me answer for this . thank you.

Comment: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Upload-Files-to-Google-Drive-using-Google-Drive-API-in-ASPNet-with-C-and-VBNet.aspx Check out this link...

Comment: I seen this link before but I need solution without ASPSnippets.GoogleAPI DLL. If you have solution then provide without ASPSnippets.GoogleAPI DLL file, Thank you.